How to create an exact stopwatch in the iOS Interactive Widget?
I want to make exact stopwatch in iOS Interactive Widget.
When I tap start button, stopwatch will be started. (startValue is 10, step by -1, update per 1 second)
ex) 10 -> 9 -> 8....
When I tap start Button again, stopwatch will restart. value will update 10 and restart.
But I have some problems. Timeline update can't update per 1 second.
Sometime count exactly, but sometimes timeline update per 2 second.ex) 0 -> 2 -> 4
I think update is not exactly because iOS operating system controls it.
I want to count always per 1 second. How to solve it? please help.. T_T
My AppIntentTimelineProvider is this.
class Provider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date:Date() , configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent(), remainingSeconds: 999)
    }

    func snapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> SimpleEntry {
            SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration, remainingSeconds: 9)
    }
    
    func timeline(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<SimpleEntry> {
            
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        print("timeline called")
        
        let sec = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "start") as? Date
        guard sec != nil else {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value : 5, to : Date())!
            entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration, remainingSeconds: 10))
            return Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        }
        
        for i in 0...10 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value : i, to : Date())!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date : entryDate, configuration: configuration, remainingSeconds: 10 - i)
            entries.append(entry)
        }
        
        return Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
         
    }
    
}

SimpleEntry have remainingSeconds. when I tap start button, UserDefault key start will  be updated and stopwatch start.
Widget have simple text and button.
button will start App Intent and text display remainingSeconds.
struct WeatherWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(entry.remainingSeconds)")
                .frame(width: 150, height : 50)
            Button(intent: NumberUpIntent()) {
                let s = entry.remainingSeconds > 0 ? "arrow.clockwise" : "play"
                Image(systemName: s).resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            }
        }
    }
}

thanks.

If you display time just in Text, then use style: timer parameter: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/displaying-dynamic-dates

I tried Text and use style:Timer and It works exactly. But I want to display only seconds. It display min:sec. I searched lot but cant find remove min and just display second. Is any way to remove minute? thanks.
